# Recover lost SSH key that is still cached on ssh-add

Tags: ssh

I made a mistake and deleted my ssh key, but `ssh-add -l` still lists it and when I do connect to a server using ssh, it will recognize it and connect, making me believe that the private key is still stored somewhere on `ssh-add`.

Is there a way to recover that key?

Thanks.

Comment: A better bet would be to use the stored key to log into those servers and set up a new key.

Comment: @NateEldredge already did that :) but that key is special, I have it set on dozens of locations.

Comment: Then I think you get to attach a debugger to the running `ssh-agent` and try to find your private key in its memory.  Maybe someone here will be familiar enough with the source to give you an idea what part of the code to search for its address.  If your installation provides an unstripped binary or a symbol table for `ssh-agent`, that may make it simpler.  Don't expect it to be simple, in any case.